# Cannot close Activity from AlertDialog called in PostExecute

Tags: android, android-activity, sdk, android-asynctask, android-alertdialog

I have a couple of Activities both of which send files up to the internet.

I would like to put the posting procedure into a separate class file so that the same procedure is called for each activity.

I pass the context of the calling activity to the main AsyncTask method which, in turn calls preExecute, doInbackground, Postexecute.

I have an AlertDialog, built using the context passed to the AsyncTask, in the postexecute method that shows the message returned by the server, with an OnClickListener to dismiss it.  When the button is clicked the alertdialog is closed but the underlying activity screen is not.

I've tried several different combinations of finish() including:-

```
dialog.cancel();
finish();
```

and

```
dialog.cancel();
MyActivity ma = new MyActivity();
ma.this.finish();
```

nothing, though, will close the Activity.

What am I doing wrong and what do I need to do to get it to close?

So far the only way I can get it to work is to embed the exact same code in both Activities which seems to me to be both inefficient and susceptible to error.

Any help would be very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I pass the context of the calling activity to the main AsyncTask

instead of only passing context of Activity you will need to pass Activity instance to class in which extending `AsyncTask` class because finish method is from `Activity` class instead of from `Context` .so try it as:

```
public class Networkasynctask extends AsyncTask<...>{

Activity activity;
Context context;

public Networkasynctask(Context context,Activity activity,...){
  this.activity=activity;
  .....
}
....
}
```

and pass Activity instance as from Activity:

```
Networkasynctask networktaskobj=new Networkasynctask(this);
```

now use `Networkasynctask.this.activity.finish()` for closing Activity from non Activity class

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and it made no difference (but I may well have misunderstood what you were suggesting.  What is hte significance of networktaskobj as I can't see that being used anywhere?

Comment: OK, I've now got it to work!  I'm not entirely sure what I did but I think it was to do with the same variable names being used for context and activity elsewhere in the main class file.  Anyway, many thanks for the solution.